# How to edit a linkedlistnode's value

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a program that creates a linkedlist having a structure as nodes. At a certain point I need to change some values inside of a particular node (structure). Here is some code:

```
Structure tp
   Dim a as double
   Dim b as integer
End Structure

Sub main()
   Dim lst as new LinkedList(of tp)
   Dim node as tp
   node.a = 10.1
   node.b = 1
   lst.addfirst(node)

   '......
   ' Now I want to change the value of first node
   lst.first.value.a = 2 
   ' But I get "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment."

End Sub
```

How do I perform such a modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple - replace your structure with a class and adjust usage accordingly:

```
Class tp
  Public a As Double
  Public b As Integer
End Class

Sub main()
  Dim lst As New LinkedList(Of tp)
  Dim node As New tp
  node.a = 10.1
  node.b = 1
  lst.AddFirst(node)
  lst.First.Value.a = 2
End Sub
```

Problem was that structures are passed by value, unlike classes, so Value will return a copy of the object, rather than a copy of the reference to that object. In the down-on-earth terms it means you cannot change the original object. With a class, you can.

I would always recommend using classes, probably because I am more used to them, and so biased to recommend them. But if you decide to use a Structure, please make sure you are aware of the differences:

- [Structures and Classes (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hkbth2a.aspx)

Comment: That will change the value of "a" inside the LinkedList?!

Comment: @tweellt: You were right, I did not pay enough attention to the code I posted. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks.It seems to work. Do you have any clue on how would this change affect the performance?

Comment: @user2622509: The difference should be insignificant. You may be losing performance on memory allocation in this case. Stack allocation should be slightly faster than heap. In practice, use profiler to get real data. Make a fake loop 100M times, using one way and the other. Compare your results. I would be using Classes anyway, even if it hurts performance a bit. The convenience I get in return is priceless.

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinkedList` is of type `tp` so its value is a `tp` type object.

In order to change the value you have to provide a new structure:

```
dim newtp as tp
newtp.a = 2
newtp.b = lst.first.value.b
```

Then `AddBefore` this `newtp` and `Remove` the old one.

Comment: I was hopping for a simpler and faster method ... This way came to my mind but there are too many steps for a simple modification.